# Swift - call @IBAction method in viewDidLoad without parameter

Tags: swift, parameters, ibaction

```
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    println("getNewPhotoAction")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getNewPhotoAction(sender: AnyObject) // Error
}
```

I just want to call the `getNewPhotoAction` IBAction method in `viewDidLoad`.

Which parameter to enter in this line -> `self.getNewPhotoAction(?????)` ?

I don't have any parameter. I just need to call.

I used in Objective-C style:

```
[self getNewPhotoAction:nil]
```

but I don't know Swift style.

Comment: Pass self as AnyObject i.e self.getNewPhotoAction(self)

Comment: @himanshu-padia Do not add blockquotes for things that are not code. And if you edit, don't forget to properly capitalize nouns and to fix errors. Just editing to add the language name in blockquotes is not acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 42):

The parameter `sender` indicates who are calling the action method.
When calling from `viewDidLoad`, just pass `self` to it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getNewPhotoAction(self)
}
```

By the way, if the `sender` parameter of the `getNewPhotoAction` method wasn’t used, the parameter name can be omitted.

```
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction(AnyObject) {
    println("getNewPhotoAction")
}
```

Comment: Only do this as a last resort, IBActions are intended to be colled from the user interface code. Calling these directly is unexpected and will result in code that is difficult to follow and understand.

Answer (score 5):

You could always create a separate func that you call on in your viewDidLoad or in your IBAction

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.getNewPhoto()
}

func getNewPhoto(){
    //do whatever you want here. 
    println("getnewphotoaction")
    println("whatever you want")
}
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.getNewPhoto()
}
```

Comment: yep.. it's good solution. but i want to call method direct..anyway thanks your answer

Comment: This adds a small though unnecessary amount of bulk to the code.

Comment: @Amerino solution is better. It introduces an intermediate, understandable abstraction. But if you really want to call it directly, check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.2

```
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction(sender: Any) {
    println("getNewPhotoAction")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getNewPhotoAction(AnyObject.self)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you still need to reference the `UIButton` or whatever is sending the action and want to call it from code at the same time - you can do this too:

`onNext(UIButton())`

Wasteful, but less code.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to pass `any object` at all. If you have no need to use the `sender`, then declare the `function` without it like this:

```
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction() { ... }
```

And use it like this:

```
self.getNewPhotoAction()
```

You may need to re-connect the outlet in `interface builder` when you make this change (remove it and then add it back) if this method is connected to an event in `interface builder`.

Comment: 99% of the ibactions have no use for the sender. This both works around the swift mangling issue that went awry in xcode 8 AND makes code more compact. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction(sender: AnyObject?){
    ......
}

**AnyObject** means that you have to pass kind of Object which you are using, nil is not a AnyObject.
But **AnyObject?**, that is to say AnyObject is Optional, nil is a valid value.
meaning the absence of a object.

self .getNewPhotoAction(nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func getNewPhotoAction(sender: AnyObject? = nil) {
    print("getNewPhotoAction")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getNewPhotoAction(nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any sender, hand over `nil`.

```
self.getNewPhotoAction(nil)
```

Comment: `getNewPhotoAction`s signature will need to be changed to `AnyObject?` if you want to pass nil.

Comment: self.getNewPhotoAction(nil) -> I already tried but it's error